# How to get multiple value of input field which is inside foreach loop using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<script>
    $("#submit").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        subjectID = $("#subjectID").val();
        subject = $("#subject_"+subjectID).val();
        subject_code = $("#subject_code_"+subjectID).val();
        internal_marks = $("#internal_marks_"+subjectID).val();
        external_marks = $("#external_marks_"+subjectID).val();

        alert(subjectID);
        alert(subject);
        alert(subject_code);
        alert(internal_marks);
        alert(external_marks);
    });
</script>   
<?php
    foreach ($subject as $row) 
    {
?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="select2-wrapper">
                    <input type="hidden" name="subjectID" id="subjectID" value="<?php echo $row['subjectID']; ?>">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject_<?php echo $row['subjectID']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['subject']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="select2-wrapper">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject_code_<?php echo $row['subjectID']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['subject_code']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="select2-wrapper">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="internal_marks_<?php echo $row['subjectID']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="select2-wrapper">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="external_marks_<?php echo $row['subjectID']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success add-btn" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div>
```

In this code I have multiple input field inside foreach loop and I want get all value using jquery but here what happen when I click on submit button and I am able to fetch only single row value. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID (here, `subjectID`).

Comment: I have diffrent `subjectID` when new row generated @Jeto

Comment: OK, well that's not what your HTML is implying though (`id="subjectID"` is a string that won't change between iterations).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First add a new class to your row like below:

```
<?php
    foreach ($subject as $row) 
    {
?>
<div class="form-group someClass">
//-------------------------^
```

Then use `each` and find value in loop like this:

```js
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('.someClass').each(function() {
    subjectID = $(this).find("#subjectID").val();
    subject = $(this).find("#subject_" + subjectID).val();
    subject_code = $(this).find("#subject_code_" + subjectID).val();
    internal_marks = $(this).find("#internal_marks_" + subjectID).val();
    external_marks = $(this).find("#external_marks_" + subjectID).val();

    console.log(subjectID);
    console.log(subject);
    console.log(subject_code);
    console.log(internal_marks);
    console.log(external_marks);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group someClass">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="hidden" name="subjectID" id="subjectID" value="1">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject_1" value="1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject_code_1" value="1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="internal_marks_1" value="1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="external_marks_1" value="1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<!-- s2 -->

<div class="form-group someClass">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="hidden" name="subjectID" id="subjectID" value="2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject_2" value="2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject_code_2" value="2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="internal_marks_2" value="2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="external_marks_2" value="2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success add-btn" id="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</div>
```

Just copy `js` part and do not use my `html` because I edited and used some sample `values` also I recommend you to get result as `array`, `object`.

```js
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let array = [];
  $('.someClass').each(function() {

    subjectID = $(this).find("#subjectID").val();
    subject = $(this).find("#subject_" + subjectID).val();
    subject_code = $(this).find("#subject_code_" + subjectID).val();
    internal_marks = $(this).find("#internal_marks_" + subjectID).val();
    external_marks = $(this).find("#external_marks_" + subjectID).val();

    obj = {
      id: subjectID,
      subject: subject,
      subject_code: subject_code,
      internal_marks: internal_marks,
      external_marks: external_marks
    }

    array.push(obj)

  });
  console.log(array)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group someClass">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="hidden" name="subjectID" id="subjectID" value="1">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject_1" value="1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject_code_1" value="1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="internal_marks_1" value="1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="external_marks_1" value="1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<!-- s2 -->

<div class="form-group someClass">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="hidden" name="subjectID" id="subjectID" value="2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject_2" value="2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject_code_2" value="2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="internal_marks_2" value="2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="select2-wrapper">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="external_marks_2" value="2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success add-btn" id="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have got all value in consol log @Pedram but I want to know how to pass this array through ajax and get reponse in alert

Comment: @navi this is new question, you can pass this array as `data` via `ajax`, in your `ajax` request use data like this: `data: array` and in respond get the result message